# Above cabinet LED light placement

Tags: lighting, cabinets

I am considering installing LED tape lights for under/above cabinets in my kitchen.  For under cabinet lighting, placement is easy and obvious.

For above cabinet lights, I wonder what to do.  The cabinets (not my kitchen, but the cabinet placement is similar)... http://st.houzz.com/simgs/c7a1f969008dcfa3_4-1019/traditional-kitchen-lighting-and-cabinet-lighting.jpg

Viewing from the top, would I just run a strip of lights along the front panel on top of the cabinets, or would I follow the entire perimeter (as in the side, the front, and the other side, etc)?

Comment: This is a matter of your personal preference, but I would try just a strip along the **back**, I think you will like the effect.

Answer (score 1):

This is a matter of personal preference, however that being said you should avoid direct line of sight with the strip.

For example, if you can see the LED strip while walking down stairs then it would be better to adjust the strip as to avoid this if possible as they are pretty intense on the eyes.

An easy to make wooden lighting rail that basically looks like a triangle would direct the light up on the wall which has a nice effect and also keeps the light away from the eyes.